# Going from the carousel page to the carousel view

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I read the following message on the page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page

> The CarouselPage has been superseded by the CarouselView, which
>   provides a scrollable layout where users can swipe to move through a
>   collection of items. For more information about the CarouselView, see
>   Xamarin.Forms CarouselView.

In this regard, I decided to start using the CarouselView.
But when I tried to use the carousel to look out for the page carousel and got an error: the ElementTemplateContent property was set more than once.

```
<CarouselView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"     
       x:Class="test.Corusel">
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:Page1></local:Page1>
            <local:Page2></local:Page2>
        </DataTemplate>

    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Here is the result I want to get.

```
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"     
       x:Class="test.Corusel">
    <CarouselPage.Children>
            <local:Page1></local:Page1>
            <local:Page2></local:Page2>
    </CarouselPage.Children>
```

I wanted to use the carousel view because I need indicators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` contains 2 child elements. Remove one and it will work.

There can be only be 1 template content inside `DataTemplate`.

If you want to use both,you can add both pages in any single layout like `StackLayout`,`ContentView`,`ContentPage` etc:

```
<CarouselView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
   xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   mc:Ignorable="d"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"     
   x:Class="test.Corusel">
<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackLayout>
              <local:Page1></local:Page1>
              <local:Page2></local:Page2>
        </StackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>

</CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

Or

you can merge both pages code into a single page

Comment: but I need the result to be like here ```<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"     
       x:Class="test.Corusel">
    <CarouselPage.Children>
            <local:Page1></local:Page1>
            <local:Page2></local:Page2>
    </CarouselPage.Children>```

Comment: tried your example, got the following error: a value of type Page1 cannot be added to a collection or dictionary IList1. Page content: Page1```<ContentPage> code ... </ContentPage>```

Comment: Not sure if it will work , but try ` <ContentPage>
              <local:Page1></local:Page1>
              <local:Page2></local:Page2>
        </ContentPage>`.Let me know

Comment: Also, please make sure that, that you can use ONLY 1 TEMPLATE. and only binded values can be changed.
Go through this link again ,if you are not getting how to use it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data

Comment: does not work ```<ContentPage> <local:Page1></local:Page1> <local:Page2></local:Page2> </ContentPage>```

Comment: Okay then, Create a new "View" with UI you want to create.Remember, You can't have different UI inside Carousel View but you can have different source values.
Bind necessary values to the "View" you have created

Comment: I caught the point. But I have a question. How to anchor the whole page?

Comment: Not sure,what you are asking. What do you mean by Anchor ?

Comment: And can you please upvote this answer,if it helped you ?

Comment: i did like this ```<CarouselView>
        <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <local:View2></local:View2><local:View1></local:View1>
                
               
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    </CarouselView>``` but when I launch the application I see a white screen. There are no errors. Maybe you need to add something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataTemplateSelector` if you need different templates for different items: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/populate-data#choose-item-appearance-at-runtime